# Create a powerful dictionary

Tags: c++, design-patterns, dictionary

I want to creat a class or something in order to store different kinds of information, like string, map, bool, int, etc.

I want to do is like:

```
dictionary func(dictionary & dict){}.
```

And the content in the dictionary is not fixed, maybe I use func1(), and func2(), but they require different arguments.

For now, I created a class to store arguments, it has different kinds of members, is it a good way? Or I need to find a good solution? Thanks

Comment: Show us what you have written so far

Comment: Use [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) together with [Boost any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/any.html)?

Comment: The big question is whether you want your dictionary to be strictly typed or not. And if yes, "how much so". As in: Will keys always be the same type (such as std::tring)? Will values always share the same base class, or will you instead go with some kind of casting/type inference to get the values out? A few use cases will also help bring focus on what you actually need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be best served by leveraging the existing [`std::undordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) hashtable/map implementation perhaps in combination with [`boost.any`](http://www.boost.org/libs/any/) if you want to mix key or value types.